# ionic 4 Angular PWA customized url

Tags: angular, routes, ionic4, progressive-web-apps

I am developing a web app with Ionic 4 & angular 7. when i visit my domain it automatically redirects to home. I would like to use a variable instead of home

e.g.

```
www.mydomain.com/home/school1 to
www.mydomain.com/school1
www.mydomain.com/school2 etc
```

So far i have this in my code which works

```
    const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule',
        canActivate: [BeforeLoginService]
      },
      {
         path: 'home/:school_name',
         loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule',
         canActivate: [BeforeLoginService]
       }, 
{ 
path: 'school-dashboard', 
loadChildren: './schools/school-dashboard/school-dashboard.module#SchoolDashboardPageModule' },
  { 
path: 'admin-dashboard', 
loadChildren: './admin/admin-dashboard/admin-dashboard.module#AdminDashboardPageModule' },]
```

So far I have tried the below code. This messes with routing. router.navigateByUrl or router.navigate does not work when I implement this code

```
const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
         path: ':school_name',
         loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule',
         canActivate: [BeforeLoginService]
       },{ 
path: 'school-dashboard', 
loadChildren: './schools/school-dashboard/school-dashboard.module#SchoolDashboardPageModule' },
  { 
path: 'admin-dashboard', 
loadChildren: './admin/admin-dashboard/admin-dashboard.module#AdminDashboardPageModule' }
      ]
```

Is there a way to accomplish a customized url in angular like below

```
www.mydomain.com/school1 or www.mydomain.com/school2 instead of www.mydomain.com/home/school1
```

Greatly appreciate any help

Comment: could you explain more why you want to do that?

Comment: so my clients can go directly to their section using their school name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule',
  canActivate: [BeforeLoginService]
},
{
 path: ':school_name',
 loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule',
 canActivate: [BeforeLoginService]
}]
```

Please check a working demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-root-params).

---

**Update**

Please try these routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule',
    canActivate: [BeforeLoginService]
  },
  {
     path: ':school_name',
     loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule',
     canActivate: [BeforeLoginService]
  },
  { 
     path: 'school-dashboard', 
     loadChildren: './schools/school-dashboard/school-dashboard.module#SchoolDashboardPageModule' 
  },
  { 
     path: 'admin-dashboard', 
     loadChildren: './admin/admin-dashboard/admin-dashboard.module#AdminDashboardPageModule'
  }
 ];
```

In this way, when the user enters `mydomain.com/school1`, the app will show the HomeComponent which is the Login page. From there, you can take the `school1` as a parameter using:

```
this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('school_name')
```

With this parameter, you will know which school has entered, so you can show the related info and then authenticate the user. Afterwards, you will have to navigate using:

```
this.router.navigate(['/school-dashboard']);
```

Please note that you will need to handle if the user didn't enter the school name in the URL, so the param will be `undefined`. You need to show something default, or show another page instead of the HomeComponent. You can do this by changing the first route to point to another Component:

```
{
  path: '',
  loadChildren: './MY_OTHER_COMPONENT_MODULE_PATH#MY_OTHER_COMPONENT_MODULE'
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But router.navigateByUrl or router.navigate isnt working once i change to this. But if the path is path: 'home:/school_name' works perfectly. My home page is also the login page

Comment: Can you please add what is your `router.navigateByUrl` / `router.navigate` looks like?

Comment: @yazantanhan my router.navigateByUrl looks like this... `if(user_type == 'school') { return this.router.navigateByUrl('/school_dashboard') else if(user_type == 'admin') {return this.router.navigateByUrl('/admin_dashboard')}`

Comment: There is no `/school_dashboard` or `/admin_dashboard` routes. What will happen with this solution that it will have `school_dashboard` as a param to the `home` component. But, when you enter `www.mydomain.com/school2` it will show the `home` page and send `school2` as a param. If you want to have `school_dashboard` and `admin_dashboard` as routes, you will need to add them to the `routes` variable. But if they are just variables passed to the home page, it should work

Comment: @yazantanhan you are correct. That is what is happening. Is there a work around for this. I have updated my question. sorry for the omission. Appreciate your help so far

Comment: No worries. I just want to make sure first, when do you want to show the `HomePage`? As now you have three routes: `school_dashboard`, `admin_dashboard` and `home` is the default, what is the flow for a user?

Comment: @yazantanhan my home page is a login page. If a user goes to www.mydomain.com/school1 I query the database and show the schools logo in the page. After login if the `user type` is `school` I use `navigateByUrl` to go to the school_dashboard. I have almost 25 other route which I didnt specify to avoid clutter in my ques. These routes are for eg: `exams/:school_id` or `batches/:school_id`. Your solution worked for a bit but when I reloaded the page it kicked me out to home page as you pointed out in your comment before I updated my question. Hope I was able to present my problem. Thanks for help

Comment: I updated the post. Please let me know if you have other questions or need more clarifications.

Comment: It worked! I had to remove canActivate from my home route. Thank you for your patience and persistence. Truly appreciate it

Comment: That's great news! Happy to help!